# Let $r\in\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt2]$. Show $\phi(r) = r$ if and only if $r\in\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Let $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt2]=\{a+b\sqrt2 \mid a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ and define $\phi:R \rightarrow R$ by $\phi(a+b\sqrt2)=a-b\sqrt2$. Show $\phi(r) = r$ if and only if $r\in\mathbb{Q}$.

My approach is that if $r\in\mathbb{Q}$, then the $b\sqrt2$ part must be zero since $\sqrt2$ is irrational, then I have $\phi(a)=a$. If $\phi(r)=r$, then r must be rational since $\sqrt2$ is irrational. I think this is just a very rough thought, can someone help shape it? Many thanks!

Comment: General approach looks about right, with one caveat: how do you guarantee that $b\in\mathbb{Q}\Rightarrow b\sqrt{2}\notin\mathbb{Q}$? Obviously $b=\sqrt{2}\Rightarrow b\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{Q}$, but that violates $b\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I didnt overlook anything:
$$\phi(a+b \sqrt2)=a+b \sqrt2=a-b \sqrt2$$
So you get: $$b \sqrt2=0$$ Hence r=a
The other direction looks fine to me. Might need to put mor emphasis on why $b\sqrt2\;$ is irrational and that $a+b\sqrt2$ is irrational then.

Answer (score 1):

One direction looks fine, but needs a bit more justification. (You may find a contrapositive approach easier.) For the other, set $$a-b\sqrt2=:\phi(a+b\sqrt2)=a+b\sqrt2$$ and conclude from there.